# EF move migration to new project

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I'm refactoring a project and want to move all the EF entities and the code-first migrations to a new project. I renamed the ContextKey in the _Migrations table to the new namespace. When running an Add-Migration, no new changes are detected (Up() and Down() are empty).
But when I remove the localdb, the db isn't re-created (it did before the move). Apparently only migrations created after the move are run (but it shouldn't).

How can I make sure all migrations (also the ones before the move) are run when creating a new db?

--edit--

Never mind :(

I dragged and dropped the existing migrations to the new project and renamed the namespaces in the migration.cs files, but forgot the code behind migration.Designer.cs

Comment: may be u shuld delete post then?

Comment: Then no-one can learn from my mistake.

Answer (score 4):

You can update all the **ContextKey** column values in the dbo._MigrationHistory table to match the new namespace and that's all.

For me i was moving all the code first models from ASP.NET MVC app to external Class library to share with other projects.

Below steps may help

1. check the dbo._MigrationHistory and you can see all records have
   similar values which match the exact class of Configuration class

> ```
> MyApp.Migrations.Configuration
> ```

2.(test step) run Update-Database from Package Manager Console with new class library selected and you will see for example below error

> ```
> There is already an object named 'AspNetRoles' in the database.
> ```

3. update all the records in the ContextKey column of _MigrationHistory table to match the new namespace

> ```
> MyApp.Domain.Migrations.Configuration
> ```

Comment: it is also answered in following question http://stackoverflow.com/q/30187115/184572

Answer (score 0):

The reference table [__MigrationHistory] contains a ContextKey column. Unless otherwise valued, it maintains the value of the membership of DbContext namespace.

You can set a class that derives from dbMigrationsConfiguration  and set the ContextKey value in the constructor.

```
public sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<Your.Context>
{
   public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
        ContextKey = "PreviousValue";
    }

    protected override void Seed(Your.Context context)
    {
        //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

        //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
        //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data. E.g.
        //
        //    context.People.AddOrUpdate(
        //      p => p.FullName,
        //      new Person { FullName = "Andrew Peters" },
        //      new Person { FullName = "Brice Lambson" },
        //      new Person { FullName = "Rowan Miller" }
        //    );
        //
    }
}
```